# Limit access to cases user created in Salesforce Community

Tags: community, case, sharing

I'm setting up a private Salesforce Community based on the Napili template and I want to show community members those cases created by them.

So far I can only give all or nothing access to cases based on profile. If I changed the Organization-Wide Sharing Defaults to Private then I'm concerned the reps won't have access to cases unless they are assigned to them or they are a member of the queue it is assigned. However, I don't believe changing the sharing settings to private will solve this problem either.

It seems I need to somehow limit access to cases in the community based on the Created By field.

Is there any way to do this?

Comment: from profile remove Read All, Modify Allpermissio. And Set the external OWDto private

Answer (score 1):

To address different sharing model for portal users or community users and internal users ,Salesforce has external Organization Wide Defaults .

You may keep the external Organization Wide Defaults as private and keep internal Access as Public read Only or read Write without providing Modify All .

Check below screenshot on how to enable external sharing rules

[image]

Please take a look at [official documentation](https://help.salesforce.com/HTViewHelpDoc?id=security_owd_external.htm&language=en_US) to check whether licence you have allocated to your community profile qualify under these .